# Core Data add relationship value

Tags: core-data, mutable, nsset

I have two entities:

```
extension Meet {

    @NSManaged var meetAllAroundScore: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var meetBarPlace: String?
    @NSManaged var meetBarScore: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var meetBeamPlace: String?
    @NSManaged var meetBeamScore: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var meetDate: String?
    @NSManaged var meetDateSort: String?
    @NSManaged var meetFloorPlace: String?
    @NSManaged var meetFloorScore: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var meetLocation: String?
    @NSManaged var meetName: String?
    @NSManaged var meetStatus: String?
    @NSManaged var meetTime: String?
    @NSManaged var meetTimeSort: String?
    @NSManaged var teamPlace: String?
    @NSManaged var gymnasts: NSSet?

}

extension Gymnast {

    @NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var gender: String?
    @NSManaged var isActive: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var level: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var picture: NSData?
    @NSManaged var telephone: String?
    @NSManaged var usag: String?
    @NSManaged var meets: NSSet?

}
```

I posed this question before on how to set new meet to all gymnasts and was told I needed to add these extensions which I have done after changing relationship to many to many.

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    func addObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.addObject(value)
    }

    func removeObject(value: NSManagedObject, forKey key: String) {
        let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey(key)
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong?

```
if let meetname = meetNameText.text {

                item.meetName = meetname

                //let newMeet = meetNameText.text
                let newMeet = item.gymnasts!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
                let items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("gymnasts")
                items.addObject(newMeet)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get all gymnasts in a set and create a new meet. To set the gymnasts of the new meet to the set of gymnasts you do:

```
newMeet.gymnasts = setOfGymnasts
```

This replaces all related gymnasts but a new meet doesn't have any.

To add one gymnast to an existing meet:

```
let items = meet.mutableSetValueForKey("gymnasts")
items.addObject(gymnast)
```

To add a set of gymnasts to an existing meet:

```
let items = meet.mutableSetValueForKey("gymnasts")
items.unionSet(setOfGymnasts)
```

You can also use other methods of `NSMutableSet` like `removeObject` and `minusSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Very simple explanation. Congratulation!